# Text not show up in p tag

Tags: css, html, hover

My goal is to hover on `next_wrapper`  and `nav_text_title_next` appears.
Now both the image and the p tag `nav_text_title_next` appears, but unfortunately I can't see any of the text in p tag `nav_text_title_next`. I use the same code for other sections, and it works well but it's not working in this part. Can you help me figure out what goes wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="next_wrapper" id="next_wrapper_title" style="position:absolute; left:1050px; top:300px; z-index:5;">
            <a class="next_button" href="#blah" style="background:none;">
                <p class="navigation_text_next" id="nav_text_title_next">
                    HI!
                </p>
                <img class="next_button" src="img/next-icon.gif" onmouseover="this.src='img/next-icon-stop2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='img/next-icon.gif'">
            </a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.next_wrapper {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 95px;
}

#nav_text_title_next {
    display: none;
}

#next_wrapper_title:hover #nav_text_title_next {
    display: block;
}

.next_button {
    width:75px;
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.navigation_text_next {
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        font-family: AvenirLTStd-Medium;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 11px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px; 
        height: 55px;
        top: 30px;
        left: 67px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px; 
        padding-left: 45px; 
        padding-right: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        display: none;
    }

.next_button {
        width:75px;
        background: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Comment: I just tested it on jsbin and seems to work fine as I can see the p text, although the position absolute is causing wired display ... so I think you can style your #nav_text_title_next on #next_wrapper_title hover

Comment: @Shina Thanks for your suggestion! I just realize that this happens because I mess something up in the div wrapping the dive I have here. So problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

your display is none delete that and you will see your text
also delete it on your image

then do something similar to this

in html

```
<p>bla</p>
```

in css

```
p {
 opacity:0;
}

p:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have hidden it from view that is why.

```
.navigation_text_next {
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        font-family: AvenirLTStd-Medium;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 11px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px; 
        height: 55px;
        top: 30px;
        left: 67px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px; 
        padding-left: 45px; 
        padding-right: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        display: none; <-- remove this
    }
```

You can remove `display: none;` as it parents is hiiden and not required.